# Is there a way to script Gmail to perform an action upon receipt of an email?

Tags: email, gmail

In Gmail, I have a filter set so that if an email from a particular sender is received, the email is forwarded to the email address used to send me a text.  That's fine, but I would really like to be able to just send a notification text not containing the entire email.

When I look at the filter options, I can set it to forward, delete it, apply a label, and so on.  But I would really like to perform some rather more complicated operation, such as the one I described.  Is there a way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger a Google Apps Script once an email get in the inbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108478/how-to-trigger-a-google-apps-script-once-an-email-get-in-the-inbox)

Answer (score 0):

Upon discovering that this was a possible duplicate, I checked the question/answer that was indicated and found that there is such a thing as Google Apps scripting.  I had previously not known there was such a thing, but suspected that there might be such.  However, not knowing what it was called, or really its nature, it was hard to hunt it down.

So here we have it: [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

Now all I have to do is learn how to use it.  So, off I go!