# Create records in AppMaker from email

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm working on a Support Ticket system with AppMaker and was wondering if there was a way to create tickets from emails.  For example, if I connected our support email to AppMaker and it captures the sender, subject and body of the email to create the new ticket record.  I have been doing some research but can't seem to find what I'm looking for...

Comment: If you already have the info in appmaker, use the client api to achieve this task. https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#Record

Comment: the point is that the info is in the mail, as I understand the question, and I have the same problem... I want the info outside from appmaker being stored in appmaker...

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I found is described here:

[Google gmail script that triggers on incoming email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50032950/google-gmail-script-that-triggers-on-incoming-email)

However, this requires to setup incoming mails in a special label, and then scan that folder every few minutes to detect incoming tickets. Might work for you if you can live with the delays. I'd really prefer a incoming email trigger for gmail, but that does not seem to exist :(