# Hangouts Chat Email alert like slack email app

Tags: gmail-api, google-hangouts

I'm looking to move from Slack to Hangouts Chat, but heavily rely on getting alerts on chat sent from email.  What's the easiest way to create an Alert in Hangouts Chat like the Email App in Slack.

The way the Slack App works is that it provides a specialized email address like: randomKey@company.slack.com

then when an email is received to the specialized email address it posts the contents to a channel.

any help would be appreciated. Currently I see other suggestions out there that do time-based triggers with email filters ([How to trigger a Google Apps Script once an email get in the inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108478/how-to-trigger-a-google-apps-script-once-an-email-get-in-the-inbox)).  But not sure if this is the easiest way / best way.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no direct integration between hangouts chat and Gmail. There are some workarounds that you can use to achieve your goal. The most popular approach is to use `Push Notification Services` of `Gmail API` using `Pub/Sub` which reads a particular email received in your inbox. Receiving this email you can then invoke your hangouts chat or send alerts to hangouts chat room via `webhook`.

***[Push Notification Documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)***
***[Hangouts Chat API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/quickstart/incoming-bot-python)***

*Hope this answers your question!!!*