# Check if someone replies to my email in Gmail using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way wherein I can track if someone replies to my email using appscript? Because I have this google sheet that serves as my tracker if my email is sent & if someone replies to my email.

Answer (score 0):

Would be good to have some code as a place to start:

**In summary:**

Each message has an Id and for each message exist a threadId that groups all the messages from the same thread. So first you have to know this threadId.

If you want to track a reply over a message you have two options:

- Look for every incoming message to see if they have the same threadId
- Look for a certain threadId and see if contains more messages than the last time you'd check it

[Apps script: thread.getMessages()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getMessages())

In any case the way to go is to setup an automated script that runs every certain time checking any of the two options.

[See this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108478/how-to-trigger-a-google-apps-script-once-an-email-get-in-the-inbox) about how to setup time triggers on incoming mails,